# Magento 2 Unable to Change the Attribute Set in Magento 2 Admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, magento-admin

It shows the error message as

> A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

But there are no logs for this error message. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: What is your Magento 2 version? Run the following command in your Magento root directory to double-check log: `tail -f var/log/*`, then check if any errors pop up in the logs after you changed the attribute set. If you found any error, add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My Magento Version is 2.3.4 and I tired checking the logs. But There are no logs when I try changing the attribute set :(

Comment: Did you run the command above for sure?

Comment: Yes @TuVan. I didnt get logs in any of the files

Comment: What is the current Magento mode (developer/default/production) you are using? Where (local/dev/production) did you check this issue? Can you clear the `full_page` cache type, change the attribute set, and re-check the log?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a simple timeout, so increase your `max_execution_time` and quite possibly your `max_input_vars` in php.ini